LangChain `LLMChain` works fine but when using the `|` operator with `ChatOpenAI` and `ChatPromptTemplate` throws a `ValueError`
I am working on a chatbot using LangChain with OpenAI's gpt-3.5-turbo model. When I use the LLMChain method to combine my ChatOpenAI instance, ChatPromptTemplate, and StrOutputParser, everything works fine, and the responses are generated correctly.
However, when I use the | operator, I get the following error:
ValueError: Invalid input type <class 'dict'>. Must be a PromptValue, str, or list of BaseMessages.

Here’s the relevant part of my code:
def chatbot(input_user_message):
    # creating a prompt template
    chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", "You are a helpful AI assistant."),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history_messages"),
            ("human", "{input_user_message}"),
        ]
    )

    # initializing OpenAI Chat model
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7)

    trimmer = trim_messages(
        max_tokens=100,
        strategy="last",
        token_counter=llm,
        # Usually, we want to keep the SystemMessage
        include_system=True,
        # start_on="human" makes sure we produce a valid chat history
        start_on="human",
    )

    def get_session_history(session_id):
        if session_id not in st.session_state.store:
            st.session_state.store[session_id] = ChatMessageHistory()
        else:
            st.session_state.store[session_id].messages = trimmer.invoke(st.session_state.store[session_id].messages)
        return st.session_state.store[session_id]

    # Initializing the output parser
    output_parser = StrOutputParser()

    # Creating an LLMChain with the prompt and memory
    #conversation_chain = LLMChain(
     #   llm=llm,
     #   prompt=chat_prompt,
     #   output_parser=output_parser,  # To parse the LLM's response into a string for display
        # verbose=True,  # Displays detailed logs for debugging
    #)
    conversation_chain = llm | chat_prompt | output_parser

    model_with_memory = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
        conversation_chain,
        get_session_history,
        input_messages_key="input_user_message",
        history_messages_key="history_messages",
    )

    session_id = "1234"
    # config = {"configurable": {"session_id": session_id}}

    response = model_with_memory.invoke(
        {"input_user_message": input_user_message},
        {"configurable": {"session_id": session_id}},
    )
    print(response)
    return response["text"]

Why does the | operator fail in this case while the LLMChain works fine? Is there something specific about the input or chaining process with Runnable objects in LangChain that I might be missing?
Any guidance on how to properly use the | operator with ChatOpenAI and ChatPromptTemplate would be appreciated.
I am using python==3.12.7 langchain==0.3.9 openai==1.55.0 langchain-openai==0.2.10

solved the error it occurs when chaining components in LangChain using the | operator, and the chaining sequence is incorrect.
The | operator processes inputs sequentially. If the chain starts with the LLM (llm | chat_prompt), it tries to pass raw dict inputs to the LLM, which expects a formatted prompt (e.g., a PromptValue). This causes the error.
Solution:
Ensure the components are chained in the correct order such as it should start with a prompt and then your model/llm and other parameters etc.
conversation_chain = chat_prompt | llm | output_parser

